# How pushing back R-value temporary objects to a vector works?

Tags: c++, oop

In this piece of code, I can't understand the meaning of `Move {10}` and `move {20}` syntax.

Is that the constructor pushed back? or a specific syntax for temporary objects?

I've searched a lot before posting this question. Can someone explain to me please?

P.S: The instructor provided this example in a video tutorial said they are supposed to be temporary R-value objects.

```
class Move
{
private:
 int *data;
public:
Move (int d) {data = d}
Move (Move &&source) : data {source.data} {source.data = nullptr;}
~Move ();
};
vector <Move> vec;
vector.push_back (Move {10});
vector.push_back (Move {20});
```

Comment: The demonstrated code does not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this piece of code, I can't understand the meaning of Move {10} and move {20} syntax.

In C++ there are several ways you can create temporary (unnamed) objects. For example you can have a function that returns object of your class by value:

```
Move foobar();
```

Now when you call that function in your code result of that call would be temporary object of type `Move`. In C++ it is called to be `prvalue`, so if we push such object into a vector:

```
 vector.push_back( foobar() ); // Moves temporary returned by foobar() into vector
```

it will be moved. But in C++ there is even simpler method to create a temporary, just use class name with parameters in brackets if required:

```
Move( 123 ); // create temporary and initialize with 123
Move{ 123 }; // same as before
```

both ways is the same in this case (it can be different in certain situations, but that is out of scope of this question). So basically you create a temporary object and initialize it with that value. Then you can push that object to the vector:

```
vector.push_back( Move{10} );   // moves temporary initialized with 10 into vector
vector.push_back( Move(20) );   // moves temporary initialized with 20 into vector
```

Note if you give your objects names:

```
Move m1( 10 );
vector.push_back( m1 ); // makes copy
```

they will not be temporary anymore and vector will have to make a copy. Though there is a
way to force moving even non temporary object using `std::move()`:

```
Move m1( 10 );
vector.push_back( std::move( m1 ) ); // move m1 into vector even it is not a temporary
```

Answer (score 0):

`Move {10}` and `Move{20}` simply call the constructor `Move::Move(int)`.  That is the constructor that best matches the syntax provided.

Nothing is being moved *more* because the type is named `Move`.  Ignore the name of the class.  The name doesn't matter.

In `vector.push_back (Move {10});`, `Move {10}` creates an object of type `Move`.  It is certainly a temporary (not a named variable) and therefore an r-value.  This newly created object is pushed back.